# Store string arraylist into another

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have a string arraylist

```
List<string[]> _editingRowData = new string[] { "", "", "" };
List<string[]> tmpData = new string[] { "", "", "" };
```

now i need to add data of _editingRowData into tmpData with multiple records.

so i'm going to do?

the data is looks like

```
_editingRowData = { "01", "33", "Cat1, PBR, PPR" }
_editingRowData = { "02", "84", "TRim, Warehouse" }
```

Comment: The first two lines will not compile. Please provide a [mre], desired output and what you have tried.

Comment: P.S. `tmpData.AddRange(_editingRowData)`?

Comment: This looks like table data, so why not use a DataTable, DataRows and DataColumns? Together, these would do the apparent tracking you're trying to manually implement. Microsoft did the work for you when they produced these classes. With them you can deduce default values, original (pre-edit) values, and current (post-edit) values.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Like Guru Stron says....
So basically initialising the rows at the start needs some work and the code you currently have won't work.

What you want is something like this.

```
List<string> row1 = new List<string> { "hello", "world" };
List<string> row2 = new List<string> { "more", "words" };
        
row1.AddRange(row2);
        
foreach(var r in row1) {
            
    Console.WriteLine(r);
            
}
```

I hope that helps with your problem and you've learnt something about Lists. I've added in a Console.WriteLine as an example of seeing what's in the List and to print it out (debugging).